# Show icon along with label in dijit PopupMenuBarItem

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to display icon in menu-bar item along with its label in dijit menu bar. According to documentation we can set icon by specifying iconClass property in configuration. Following is the code but the icon is still not displayed. Is it a bug in dojo?

```
var form1 = {};

require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/MenuBar", "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem"], function (ready, MenuBar, PopupMenuBarItem) {
    ready(function () {
        form1.menu_bar = new MenuBar({}, "menu");
        form1.item1 = new PopupMenuBarItem({
            label: "Cut",
            iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"
        }, "item1");
        form1.menu_bar.addChild(form1.item1);

        form1.menu_bar.startup();
    });
});
```

JS-FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/X2xjt/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer. It is not possible to do this with `dijit/PopupMenubarItem`. Here is the reason, why http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/MenuBar.html#icons

Comment: It's a bit disappointing that a mature javascript toolkit isn't able to do this with standard widget markup. But given that "it is not possible", what is the workaround? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can simply add a div to the `PopupMenubarItem` containing the icon, using dojo's dom-construct. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is indeed correct.  If you swap out PopupMenuBarItem with `dijit/MenuItem` you'll see that the icon renders as expected next to the menu item.  PopupMenuBarItem requires the `popup` property to be specified when created (see the [reference docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/MenuBar.html)), which was causing an error to be thrown when `form1.menu_bar.startup()` was being called.

```
var form1 = {};

require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/MenuBar", "dijit/MenuItem"], function (ready, MenuBar, MenuItem) {
    ready(function () {
        form1.menu_bar = new MenuBar({}, "menu");
        form1.item1 = new MenuItem({
            label: "Cut",
            iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"
        }, "item1");
        form1.menu_bar.addChild(form1.item1);

        form1.menu_bar.startup();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X2xjt/2/

Comment: I don't think that MenuItem is intended to be used with MenuBar it should be use with Menu. Also if you add multiple menu items with this approach then each will be displayed on a new line where as we require all items to be displayed horizontally in the same line. See this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2xjt/3/

Comment: was there a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, a solution would be kind of nice wouldn't it.